# React Lifecycle Events - Child Component Inherits Old State Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, redux, react-redux

Im probably getting something not right with my understanding of states & props in React. This is using React, Redux based app.

**Scenario:**

I have a global `SVG` component, which gets the dimensions of the viewport from the app within the `componentDidMount` method.

The default (upon initialisation of the app) props of the `SVG` in the `state` are:

```
dimension : {
 width : 0,
 height : 0
}
```

The `componentDidMount` retrieves the `width` & `height` values from the DOM
and dispatches the values to the state.

Now I have a child component of `SVG` component, which needs the updated svg width & height values to calculate the *default* viewbox & update the state again. This needs to be executed only once upon mounting *(important point)*, hence the calcuation of the `viewbox` is in the `componentDidMount` of the child component.

**Whats Happening:**

However, I guess because of React batch updating the DOM, the props passed to the child component are the default initial width & height values, not the updated state after `SVG` component's `componentDidMount`.

**Question:**

How can I pass the updated state to `componentDidMount` of the child component. Note:

- I cannot use `componentDidUpdate`, which would mean, that everytime the component is updated, it will calculate the default values & update the view again, thereby, over-riding the user position.

Comment: If you set the state in *componentDidMount()* it will re-render the component. If you want to use the props from parent component you should work in *componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)*, that is called each time the component receave props from parent component.

Comment: Can you show up your code?

Comment: @MarioSantini thank you, that did it. I completely forgot about that lifecycle event :! If you want to post that as answer, I'll accept it as it was the first one.

Comment: @Kayote I post the answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the state in *componentDidMount()* than it will re-render the component.

If you want to use the *props*, you should work in *componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)*, that in the React life-cycle is called each time the component receave *props* from parent component.

That seems what you're trying to achieve so far.

Answer (score 0):

What happens in your case is that before the `componentDidMount` of the parent component executes, your child component is rendered and hence it receives the `default` props. So the props that get updated in the `componentDidMount` of the parent will reflect in your child as the updated props

You can make use of `componentWillReceiveProps` function in the child component to set the state based on the updated props.
However this will be executed everytime the props get updated from the parent, so what you can do is that pass some prop from the parent which is being set with a particular value in the `componentDidMount` of parent and later has a diffrent value. Based on this props in `componentWillReceiveProp` you can set the initial state of the child component.

Comment: Let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: Thank you for the description Shubham. I dont believe, the first para is correct. Correct me if Im wrong but the they both are pushed to DOM in one go, hence the state values being the same.

Comment: Yes the both are pushed to DOM at one do. But as you say that the componentDidMount updated the state and passes it as the prop, this action takes time. and hence the initialstate is only passed to the child component. Its only when the state is updated that the rerender occurs and the updated props are passed